# C# Nest Elastic Search Wildcard Query - No Results Returned

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to set up a query in C# using a wildcard. I can get the correct data returned using `MultiMatch` but have not had success with wildcard. Here is what I have so far:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResultModel>> Search(string query)
     var queryResults = await elasticApp.SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Take(10)
        .Index(activeIndices)
        .Type(dataTypes)
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(m => m
                    .Wildcard(w => w
                        .Field("name")
                            .Value(w + "*")                            
                     )
                 )
             )
         )
```

So as for the function parameter `query` when using `MultiMatch`, you would do `.Query(query)` at the end, but when I try to put that in using Wildcard I get syntax errors. And according to the NEST ES docs it seems that you do not use `.Query` at the end.

Currently an empty array is returned.

Any insight on this would be appreciated as I am new to using Nest and C#.

Comment: Take a look at the Explain API for why given document does not match a query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Comment: Thank you Russ, that was helpful. The `query` passed in needed to be `ToLower()` given an implementation set up in a separate application that expected the query string to be lowercase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by doing the following:

```
.Query(q => q                    
  .Bool(b => b                     
    .Should(m => m
      .Wildcard(c => c
        .Field("name").Value(query.ToLower() + "*")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

`query` is passed in as a function argument and I want the asterisk to take everything after `query`.

Comment: This is equivalent: `.Query(q => q.Wildcard(c => c.Field("name").Value($"{query.ToLower()}*")))`